# How to sell a design to a company?

Tags: business, design-process, product-design

I am planning to design a couple of phone cases which contain features other phone cases don't have.

My plan of action is like this:

- Design phone cases on computer
- Send emails around to companies that manufacture and sell phone cases showing my designs and asking for a certain price (like 10% sales on the phone cases)

This is first time I am doing something like this. Is the approach I am planning to do is correct in trying to get a company interested in my phones cases designs?

(If this is wrong place to ask this question then can you guide me to the correct Stack Exchange site please)

Comment: If you're strictly speaking of visual designs (aka, graphic design) there's already established sites that do this such as http://society6.com/cases On the other hand, if you're speaking about product design, then this probably isn't the right site to be asking on (though you could try another established site, http://www.quirky.com/.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*I am not a product designer, nor do I play one on social media but ...*

## Do not circulate your designs without an NDA!

You need to entice your prospective clients/manufacturers to meet with you, sign an [NDA (non-disclosure agreement)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-disclosure_agreement), then present the idea.

In a perfect world, you'd also patent your design. But that's not a cheap process and I suspect you don't have the funding for that.

Comment: In most cases though they won't. And then you have to decide if the risk is worth it. Chances are they view your idea not that brilliant anyway. Ideally, one would meet and present the idea but not leave any material that would make it easy for them to reproduce it.

Comment: Exactly this. I knew of someone who shared their designs with a company she wanted to work for without an NDA. The company stole all of her designs and she didn't get the job.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider making a prototype. [Shapeways](http://www.shapeways.com/) is a 3D printing service that can help you with that.